# 500 Internal Server Error - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, internal-server-error

I have uploaded a Wordpress site under the following subdomain - http://wptest.paddingtonterraces.com.au/

I am getting '500 Internal Server Errors' for everything that is grabbed from outside the root directory.

Any help with resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

.htaccess rewrites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /paddington-terraces/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) /paddington-terraces/wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-g2368ac2/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) /paddington-terraces/wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-g2368ac2/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) /paddington-terraces/wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-g2368ac2/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /paddington-terraces/wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /paddington-terraces/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**SOLVED:**

Had to remove */paddington-terraces* from the Rewrite paths.

Comment: Is it a fresh install? Have you set the rewrites in your .htaccess file?

Comment: It's not a fresh install, I built the site locally, uploaded it to the server and used SQL replace queries to update the URL paths. Here is me .htaccess rewrites for Wordpress:

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

1. Could be a bad plugin.

   - Disable all plugins, then refresh your homepage.
2. Bad install.

   - Go download a fresh copy from wordpress.org. Overwrite your current WP dir, with the exception of wp-contents and wp-config.
3. Bad theme code

   - Check your functions.php file
   - Even better, if you have command line access, from your main WP directory run:

     - grep -rn /home/paddingt/public_html/wptest/ gllr_add_script *
4. Bad version of PHP or Apache/HTTPD

   - echo php_info();

My bet is a bad plugin. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try To deactivate plugins and check
you can deactivate plugin without using wp-admin. Simply login with ftp and rename the plugin name for example: 'plugin_name' change to 'plugin_name_rename'.. I faced same issue .. and my problem was solved by deactivating plugin :)