# getting 500 error on wp-admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

i am having weird situation last week i open my site and then i open my wp-admin page it should work like my front but i am having 500 error.

i tried almost every thing on google to find this situation but nothing helped me.

as i remember last time i work in theme function file and WordPress config file i checked .htaccess file eveything is fine.

also i did replace content with old content and create new file for config but nothing works. i disabled all plugins enabled debug mode but nothing helped me
what should i do ? i dont want to lose anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [500 Internal Server Error - Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769262/500-internal-server-error-wordpress)

Comment: Did you try to change wp_debug to true and see if this shows any errors?

Comment: @NeilKennedy yeh i did wp_debug to true all i see is deprecated warnings and some plugins notices so i disabled plugins that causes of notices but remains all plenty of warnings something deprecated etc etc. i am not WordPress developer. all i get is that all warning is not my problem and i thought my problem is something else but i didn't know.

Comment: So when you set wp_debug to true and tried to load the wp-admin, the 500 error didn't show, just the warnings and error messages showed?  In my experience when this happens, it is one of these errors that is causing the issue with the 500 error.  Are any of the errors 'fatal'?

Answer (score 0):

Glad you sorted your error with incompatible PHP versions.

In order to properly debug an `HTTP 500` error, you should do the following.

- In your `php.ini`, set `error_reporting` to -1
- Turn `display_errors` off
- Set a custom `error_log` path.

Then in your terminal, type `tail -f /path/to/error_log`.

Now as you work on your project, you can go into your terminal and you will see all notices, warnings, deprecation messages, and fatal error messages, scrolling past in real time.

Then you can tighten the screws. An empty log means well written code!