# How to solve 500 Error issue in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I upload my website backup on my hosting, website database setup successfully but i am getting this error...`This page isn’t working` `www.example.com is currently unable to handle this request.` `HTTP ERROR 500` .
I am not understanding what is the issue, if i Upload fresh wordpress then it's working fine. Please let me know the solution for this.
`

Comment: A 500 error just means *something* went wrong. It could be anything, from a server setup (although it works with a fresh install so probably not ) to a problem in the code, either its logic or even just a syntax error. This question has been asked many times here so do a search and take a look at those answers to see if they help you narrow it down. If you find a specific error that you can't fix, then come back with the details and we can help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [500 Internal Server Error - Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769262/500-internal-server-error-wordpress)

Comment: Here are other duplicate questions that might help too: [wordpress 500 internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wordpress+500+internal+server+error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal server errors (error 500) are often caused by plugin or theme function conflicts, so if you have access to your Dashboard, try deactivating all plugins. If you don’t have access to your admin panel, try manually resetting your plugins (no Dashboard access required). If that resolves the issue, reactivate each one individually until you find the cause.

If that does not resolve the issue, try switching to the Twenty Seventeen theme to rule-out a theme-specific issue. If you don’t have access to your Dashboard, access your server via SFTP or FTP, or a file manager in your hosting account’s control panel, navigate to /wp-content/themes/ and rename the directory of your currently active theme. This will force the default theme to activate and hopefully rule-out a theme-specific issue.

If that does not resolve the issue, it’s possible that a .htaccess rule could be the source of the problem. To check for this, access your server via SFTP or FTP, or a file manager in your hosting account’s control panel, and rename the .htaccess file. If you can’t find a .htaccess file, make sure that you have set your SFTP or FTP client to view invisible files.

Comment: Your contributions are welcome and this is a good answer, but please note that answering duplicate question like this is against SO guidelines. Answers could get downvoted even if they are good! Duplicate questions mean that good answers are spread across multiple posts. Please see the "Answer well-asked questions" section in [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Instead the correct action is to flag questions as duplicates, or if it's low quality then flag or ask for more information in the comments. Or just move on to another question :)